# asp.net webapp connecting to ssrs 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

Before I get too deep into this, I want to outline what I'm trying to do.  We're trying to connect our webapp to a 2012 SSRS instance using Windows Auth, and getting a 401 unauthorized.

However, if I browse to the URL I attempt for the execution service and use the credentials I'm passing in the LogonUser method, I get the wsdl just fine.  So, I think the problem is something on the code end and not the server.  (Both browsing and webapp test happening on my machine, so I don't think it's a domain issue or something like that either).

OK, some details.

We currently have an old 2008 instance which uses some custom authentication which we want to move away from.  But still, I *think* I can use that as a model of how to connect to the 2012 execution service (or so I think), just using the windows auth credentials instead.

Our old model has a web reference to the service, and there's a class which extends that reference.  This class implements GetWebRequest and GetWebResponse like I think would be expected.  So I got a web reference to the 2012 execution service and set up a similar proxy class, extending that instead.

```
public class ReportExecutionService2012Proxy : ReportExecution2012.ReportExecutionService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Override the GetWebRequest method to attach the auth cookie.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); ;
        // if the client already has an auth cookie
        // place it in the request's cookie container
        if (AuthCookie != null)
            request.CookieContainer.Add(AuthCookie);
        request.Timeout = -1;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"]);
        return request;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override GetWebResponse to check for the auth cookie.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2201:DoNotRaiseReservedExceptionTypes")]
    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        string cookieName = response.Headers["RSAuthenticationHeader"];
        // If the response contains an auth header, store the cookie
        if (cookieName != null)
        {
            Utilities.CustomAuthCookieName = cookieName;
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
            Cookie authCookie = webResponse.Cookies[cookieName];
            // If the auth cookie is null, throw an exception
            if (authCookie == null)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "Authorization ticket not received by LogonUser");
            }
            // otherwise save it for this request
            AuthCookie = authCookie;
            // and send it to the client
            // TCK 7/25/2011: This was causing MKO to switch auth keys and force logout. I'm not sure if I'm just
            // hitting the most obvious problem and the root problem is deeper, but this does appear to fix it.
            //Utilities.RelayCookieToClient(authCookie);
        }

        if ((response is HttpWebResponse) && ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            var content = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return response;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Private property used to store the Auth Cookie.
    /// </summary>
    private Cookie AuthCookie
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_Authcookie == null)
                m_Authcookie = Utilities.TranslateCookie(Utilities.AuthSource.GetCookie(Utilities.CustomAuthCookieName));
            return m_Authcookie;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Authcookie = value;
        }
    }
    private Cookie m_Authcookie = null;
}
```

When we are ready to load the report, we instantiate this proxy (if it's not already) and attempt the login to the service.  It's at this point we get the 401.

```
    private reporting.proxy.ReportExecutionService2012Proxy _rsExec2012Proxy = null;
    public virtual reporting.proxy.ReportExecutionService2012Proxy RsExec2012Proxy
    {
        get
        {
            if (_rsExec2012Proxy == null)
            {
                _rsExec2012Proxy = new reporting.proxy.ReportExecutionService2012Proxy();

                    _rsExec2012Proxy.Url = reporting.ReportConfiguration.ReportExecutionSevice2012Url;

                    ReportServerCredentials creds =
                    new ReportServerCredentials(reporting.ReportConfiguration.ReportService2012Username,
                        reporting.ReportConfiguration.ReportService2012Password,
                        reporting.ReportConfiguration.ReportService2012Domain);
                    _rsExec2012Proxy.Credentials = creds.NetworkCredentials;




                    _rsExec2012Proxy.LogonUser(
                        reporting.ReportConfiguration.ReportService2012Username,
                        reporting.ReportConfiguration.ReportService2012Password,
                        reporting.ReportConfiguration.ReportService2012Domain); 

            }
            return _rsExec2012Proxy;
        }
    }
```

So, we get the URL to the service and the credentials out of configuration and attempt to get into the service, but no dice.

I've been reading around on this and just don't understand the problem well enough to go further.  Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first, you **only** use LogonUser when you have a custom security extension (i.e. not just using vanilla Windows / basic authentication.) And because you're using custom security, you can only call it against SSL connections.

So do you have a security extension for your 2012 instance? If not, just instantiate the service, set the Credentials property on it and then make your requests against it.

Here's [an MSDN sample of connecting against a 2005 SSRS Execution Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsexecutionservice2005.reportexecutionservice.render%28SQL.90%29.aspx) but it's pretty much remained the same up through 2012.

Comment: Thank you.  One of my co-workers realized this yesterday afternoon, and he just implemented a "proxy" over the service which didn't have the custom junk, and just sets the URL & credentials.  Seems as if it's working in the development environment.